# how to create folder if not exist in google drive in android using google drive Api?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

i have created folder into google drive but every time i run the app, same folder is creates into my google drive. i just want to find way how to avoid same folder creation in google drive.my code is hear.  if anyone have solution of this problem than let me know.

```
  @Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "API client connected.");
    MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
            .setTitle("Testing1").build();
         Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(mGoogleApiClient).createFolder(mGoogleApiClient,changeSet).setResultCallback(callback); }

final ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult> callback = new ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error while trying to create the folder", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Created a folder: " + result.getDriveFolder().getDriveId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be creating the folder in onConnected. onConnected is called every time your application is launched. I'd move the folder creation code out of onConnected.

Comment: You're not answering the question.